# I include this line "test": "tsc && concurrently \"karma start karma.conf.js\""

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, mocha.js, karma-runner

- In my package.json  I include this line "test": "tsc && concurrently \"karma start karma.conf.js\""
- but when I run npm run test I am getting the error echo 'Error: no test specified'.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- I have included all my test cases inside testing folder.
- providing my package.json and error below

```or-tag-here
{
  "name": "sports",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "sports player - ",
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.10.1"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "@ng-idle/core": "2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.10",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.18",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.1",
    "@types/webpack": "^3.0.5",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.21",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "0.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "commander": "^2.6.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "http-post": "^0.1.1",
    "http-proxy": "^1.8.1",
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    "pako": "^1.0.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "require": "^2.4.20",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "text-encoding-shim": "^1.0.0",
    "timespan": "^2.3.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts": "0.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.6",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
    "winston": "^2.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.6",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.8.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "jasmine-expect": "^3.0.1",
    "jasmine-jquery": "^2.1.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-jquery": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "karma-typescript-preprocessor": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config  ./webpack.dev.js --inline --progress --color ",
    "postinstall": "webpack -p --config ./webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "fix-memory-limit": "cross-env LIMIT=2048 increase-memory-limit",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"karma start karma.conf.js\""

  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.isports.com/player-sing/webcomponent.git"
  }
}


$ npm run test

> sports@1.0.0 test C:\Users\\Desktop\folder-1\webcomponent
> echo 'Error: no test specified'

'Error: no test specified'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
"test": "tsc && concurrently 'karma start karma.conf.js'"